# Update a column of a row on an insert trigger, the trigger is in the same table of which row is being edited

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have generated 2 Tables:

```
Associates: (Associate_ID, Name(Varchar) Number(Varchar) )
Associate_Number: (AssociateNumberId, Number(Varchar) )
```

I want to Increment the value of Number column in Associate_Number Table.
I want to update the Number column in the Associates Table with the incremented value of Number in the Associate_Number table.

I am using an after insert trigger in the Associates table to achieve it.

UPDATE `Ascociate_Number` SET `Number` = (`NUMBER` + 1) WHERE `AssociateNumberID` = 1;

UPDATE `Ascociates` SET NEW.Number = (SELECT `Number` FROM `Associate_Number` WHERE `AssociteNumberID` = 1) WHERE `AssociateNumberID` = 1;

ERROR CODE 1442 occurs while executing this statement i know that using an auto increment column can do this but i want to do it in this manner.

Please help.

Thank you for taking time to read.

Comment: if you reedit your question to be readble and show your tables, your queries and the eventual errors you got, it would be great for us and useful for you

Comment: Is the question clear sir ?